# setting attribute/node in XML in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

Here's my XML:

```
<root>
   <A id='1'>
     <B>Blah</B>
     <C>Test</C>
   </A>
</root>
```

I would like to add  under  so my final XML would like:

```
<root>
   <A id='1'>
     <B>Blah</B>
     <C>Test</C>
     <D>New value</D>
    </A>
</root>
```

I can get the node  in XPath using `//A`and I am not sure how to add or edit the values once I get the node.

Comment: There's many similar questions, please look around first. What technologies do you use and how is the value for the new node supplied? This is rather important to know. Do you use SAX, StAX, DOM, JDOM...? Are your parsing, transforming using XSLT, binding with JAXB?

Comment: I'm using DOM. I'm not using XSLT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader xml = new StringReader("<root><A id='1'><B>Blah</B><C>Test</C></A></root>");
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xml));
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//A");
Element element = doc.createElement("D");
element.setTextContent("new value");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {  
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    node.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) of the `Node` interface from DOM. `Element` extends this, so you'll first need to obtain the Element for `A`. Use [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElement%28java.lang.String%29) on your `Document` instance, or some other suitable method from the class, to create the desired `D` element, then set its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the DOM API directly, you can also use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), a simple wrapper library for DOM, that I have created:

```
// With css-style selectors
$(document).find("A").append("<D>New value</D>");

// With XPath
$(document).xpath("//A").append("<D>New value</D>");
```